# Is there a way to return to an old changeset on the same bookmark?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

My hg log was originally:

```
changeset:   9ae05c291ba8187a35f94fcf3395586524b4631c   (@)
bookmarks:   candidate_result_sid_pipeline
user:        A

changeset:   48b37bd5f15a4896f66d3b37836fddd3fdab8c79   
user:        A

changeset:   21bc68beeba31564d06719c158581bcadbc25b5f  D3406332  
user:        B
```

But I thought there were issues with it so I ran hg reset --clean tip~1. Then I made changes, committed them and my hg log was:

```
changeset:   f743bd32ab37b3025218c408c0a1309f68a45e15   (@)
bookmarks:   candidate_result_sid_pipeline
user:        A

changeset:   21bc68beeba31564d06719c158581bcadbc25b5f  D3406332  
user:        B
```

Now I realize I actually want to return to either 9ae05c291ba8187a35f94fcf3395586524b4631c or 48b37bd5f15a4896f66d3b37836fddd3fdab8c79 from the original log. Is this possible or is it lost forever since I just realized this is a hard reset?

Comment: There is no `hg reset` command; I presume you mean `hg update`, unless this is some alias or extension that you are using? In any event, all revisions should still be there, since neither `hg update` or `hg commit` would remove any revisions. I'm not sure why the old revisions do not show up on your log, unless your log command is configured (alias to use `-f`?) to only show the current branch up to the current revision or something.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends ah, this must be an extension then. I found out this is equivalent to git reset --hard HEAD~1 according to our documentation, so I don't think it was possible to go back. Either way, I just ended up re-writing my code.